# how to solve the issue with group by and aggregate function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, rdbms

I am trying to write a query for dividing the two SQL statements but it shows me

```
 ERROR: column "temp.missed" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in 
 an aggregate function
  SQL state: 42803
```

although when I do group by temp.missed, it seems to be working but shows wrong results because of multiple group by.

I have following tables in PostgreSQL

```
 create table test.appointments (
      appointment_id serial
      , patient_id integer references test.patients(id)
      , doctor_id integer references test.doctors(id)
      , appointment_time timestamp
      , appointment_status enum('scheduled','completed','missed')
      );

 create table test.visits (
      visit_id serial
      , patient_id integer references test.patients(id)
      , doctor_id integer references test.doctors(id)
      , walk_in_visit boolean
      , arrival_time timestamp
      , seen_time timestamp
      );
```

I have written following query for finding Missed appointment rate (missed appointments / total appointments) but its shows the above mentioned error.

```
  select tem.doctor_id, (temp.missed::float/tem.total) as ratio from 
    (select doctor_id, count(appointment_status) as missed from appointments 
     where appointment_status='missed' group by doctor_id)as temp
      join (select doctor_id, count(appointment_status) as total from 
      appointments group by doctor_id) as tem  on temp.doctor_id = 
       tem.doctor_id group by tem.doctor_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those subqueries - a `count` function applied to a `case` expression would be much simpler:

```
SELECT   doctor_id, 
         COUNT(CASE appointment_status 
                    WHEN 'missed' THEN 1 
                    ELSE NULL 
               END)::float / 
         COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM     appointments
GROUP BY doctor_id
```

Comment: And with PostgreSQL 9.4 you can have a nicer syntax without CASE: `COUNT(appointment_status) FILTER (WHERE appointment_status='missed')`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Even nicer! Thanks for the tip. Care to post this as an answer?

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the answer. the reason I wrote all subqueries is to generate a report  for past 7 days with the following fields: doctor_id, number of appointments, number of walk-in visits, missed appointment rate(missed appointments/total appointments), average patient timeliness for appointments (arrival time - appointment time in mintues) and average wait time(seen time-arrival time , in mintues). I can do this in mysql with multiple joins but I have no idea how to do this with postgreSQL after seeing your answer with case and filter. can you help me out solving this

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the query a lot and if you are using PostgreSQL 9.4 you can use a very nice and clear syntax:

```
SELECT   doctor_id, 
     COUNT(appointment_status)::float
       FILTER (WHERE appointment_status='missed') / 
     COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM     appointments
GROUP BY doctor_id
```

The `FILTER` will affect only the `COUNT` it is after, so in this case it will only count missed appointments.

Comment: As you stated, this is unfortunately only available since 9.4, but it's **way** cleaner than anything else. Big upvote!