# PostgreSQL how to use count with boolean true value only

Tags: postgresql, count, boolean

I'm trying to get 2 columns. One with only true values of `patient_healty` and second with all values of `patient_healty` from department.

```
select 
    count(p1.patient_health) as not_health, 
    count(patient.id) as all, 
    department.name 
from 
    department
inner join 
    doctor on department.id = doctor.department_id
inner join 
    healing on doctor.id = healing.doctor_id
inner join 
    patient as p1 on healing.patient_id = p1.id
inner join 
    patient on healing.patient_id = patient.id
group by
    department.name
```

This will return two columns of all values from `patient_health` and name of the department. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the tags to include postgresql and the version you're using. In the newer ones there's a clean solution and for older ones there's another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve the issue with group by and aggregate function in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431574/how-to-solve-the-issue-with-group-by-and-aggregate-function-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `avg()`:

```
select avg(p1.patient_health::int)
```

Comment: I changed the question to be more understandable. Thank you for your help

Comment: I think this still does what you want.